# How to restore dump file using Mysql Query Browser

Tags: mysql, database, restore, database-administration

When i am trying to run some queries from the batch file i am getting some error message in my query browser

I have tried with

```
source E:\Rename_scripts_unused_tables_msp.sql
```

and i am getting error message like

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source   E:\Rename_scripts_unused_tables_msp updated.sql' at line 1'
```

And the query works fine in command line.

**Here is my source file statements:**

```
rename table appliance_backup_usage_history to unused_appliance_backup_usage_history;

rename table backup_core_server to unused_backup_core_server;

rename table bdr_vms to unused_bdr_vms;

rename table client_details1 to unused_client_details1;

rename table client_service_technologies_backup to unused_client_service_technologies_backup;

rename table cloud_instances to unused_cloud_instances;
```

**and more statements like that**

What's the reason behind this ??

Comment: We would need to see the source file

Comment: Does the file contain `use somedatabase;`?

Comment: Yah it worked fine in command line ( i have selected the database and then ran the script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` is a `mysql` CLI command - not an SQL query command. It only works using the command line client `mysql`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html